# Running different versions of Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I intend to use different versions of PostgreSQL, one for creating a database for an application, and the other for setting up a development environment. How do I do so?

When I run PostgreSQL commands like `pg_config`, it return the version for one of the installed versions. How do ensure there is not conflict?

Comment: Have you considered using, say Docker, for your development environment?

Comment: The issue with Docker containers is limitations say like some commands that would be there in local are not there in the containers. Although, a good reference would be great.

Comment: What OS are you working with?. **Add information as text update to question**.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu

Comment: On Ubuntu  you can use the `pg_common` process to do this. If you want to use different versions then you will need to use the Postgres community repo here [PG Ubuntu repo](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/). For more information I wrote a two part blog on this [Pt 1 Install](https://aklaver.org/wordpress/2023/06/29/postgres-debian-ubuntu-packagingpart-1/) and [Part 2 Commands](https://aklaver.org/wordpress/2023/07/01/postgres-debian-ubuntu-packagingpart-2/).

Comment: Docker. Docker. Docker. This gives you extremely fine-grained control over what version(s) you're running, where they're storing data, and makes it easy to upgrade each instance individually if necessary. While Ubuntu has packages for Postgres that are versioned, they're very coarse, like 14, 15, or 16, not 15.2 vs. 15.4. If you can get one version running with [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) it's easy to stand up multiple.

Answer (score 1):

To manage multiple versions of PostgreSQL on your system without conflicts, you can use different approaches, like using Docker containers, utilizing package managers, or manually installing different versions alongside each other.
Docker allows you to run PostgreSQL in isolated containers, making it easy to manage multiple versions without conflicts.
You can pull and run different PostgreSQL versions as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed PostgreSQL using the binary packages from the PostgreSQL site, it is no problem to have clusters with different PostgreSQL versions on a single machine.

If you call a PostgreSQL executable like `pg_config`, you'll get the executable from the version that happens to be first on your `PATH`. To explicitly choose an executable from a specific PostgreSQL version, use an absolute path. This will vary depending on your operating system. Here are three examples:

```bash
/usr/pgsql-14/bin/pg_config              (Redhat-based Linux)
/usr/lib/postgresql/14/nin/pg_config     (Debian-based Linux)
C:\Programs\PostgreSQL\14\bin\pg_config  (Windows)
```

Comment: And use for every installation a different port number, like 54311 for version 11, 54312 for version 12, etc.

Comment: Or install [`pg_wrapper`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/pg_wrapper.1.html), which will make each command determine the correct client to use depending on the cluster you're trying to connect to

Answer (score 0):

This question asks whether one could use two PostgreSQL installs, one for the development and the other for prod use and to ensure compatibility.

In general it sounds like a bad idea to develop for a different version than the one you are going to actually use. But in the context of this answer I will not question your intent and will assume that you have good reason to want what you want.

I'm not sure whether you want to host the different PostgreSQL versions on the same machine or on multiple machines.

If you want to host them on the same machine, then in order to set it up, look into this excellent question and answer: [Is it possible to have two versions of PostgreSQL Server on same Fedora 37 Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75581500/is-it-possible-to-have-two-versions-of-postgresql-server-on-same-fedora-37-serve)

Or you can use Docker as ndc85430 suggested in the comment section to set up multiple instances of PostgreSQL.

Now, the next issue is compatibility.

It would make sense for your dev env to have a connection toward both the version you develop at and the prod version, so it would make sense to have a stage install of Postgres with the prod version and make sure that any alter that is being initiated is executed at both versions and if it fails at any of the versions, then it's rolled back.

Also, you will need to repeat your tests using the other database, because sometimes incompatibility manifests at the time of usage, no sign of it being shown at the time when the alter is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I just use Docker to run PostgreSQL images on different ports. It works pretty well. Docker postgres sucks a little as I still need some "native" client to psql and the like.

If you've fully installed PostgreSQL "natively" (not docker), it may be a little harder, but the key is the port you have it listening on. I'm not sure exactly *how* you would get common Postgres binaries working with unique configuration (for port and storage), but I'm sure it is possible.

Are you sure you need a 2nd postgres server? Can you get the same effect with just a unique database for testing and a different one for development?

Answer (score 0):

You can be able to run various postgresql versions on your machine in the following steps:

1.Verify the version of postgresql you have installed and want to run with this can be checked and verified by the following command

```
  /usr/psql-(version)/bin/pg_config
```

2.Set the environment variables of the specific installations

```
 e.g export PATH=/usr/psql-(version)/bin=$PATH
```

3.Change the port numbers of the various versions of postgresql installations

```
 eg.As we know the default postgresql instance runs on port 5432 so as to avoid conflicts You should configure one of the installations to listen to a different port by adding the different port number into the postgresql.conf file of that particular installation
```

4.Use separate data directories
when initializing any database cluster use different data directories for each version

5.Finally You can start the specific version of postgresql by specifying the service name

```
 e.g sudo systemctl start postgresql-(version)
```

Comment: This works, but it can also cause abject chaos. The Docker method is far simpler and easier to control, even accounting for the minor amount of time spent learning how to manage Docker processes.